# How can i assign value to a class when using an interface?

Tags: java, interface, constructor, implements

I have a Java class which implements an interface, this class have a constructor that takes a String value and all the methods is that class are rely on that value in order to get work, so, what can i do if i want to deal with the interface directly and access the methods from it and as you know the interfaces can't have constructors so i can't assign that string value from it.

**The Class:**

```
public class XmlSource implements XmlInterface{

    XmlConf xconf = new XmlConf();
    URLProcess urlp = new URLProcess();
    private URL url;
    private String surl;

    public XmlSource(String surl) throws MalformedURLException {

        this.surl = surl;
        result = urlp.validate(surl);
        if(result == true){
            configure();
        }

    }

    public boolean configure() throws MalformedURLException {

            url = new URL(surl);
            xconf.setUrl(url);
            xconf.setParameters(urlp.parameters);
            xconf.setUrlPath(urlp.path);
            xconf.setHostName(urlp.hostName);
            return result;

    }

    public Document load() throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException,
            SAXException {

        // encoding the URL
        InputStream is = url.openStream();

        // loading the XML
        domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.parse(is);

        return doc;

        }
}
```

**The Interface:**

```
public interface XmlInterface {

    public boolean configure() throws Exception;
    public Document load() throws Exception;
}
```

Comment: In order to deal with the methods in the interface, create an instance of a class that implements the interface and call the methods on the class, in your case as @TheNewIdiot said use `new XmlSource(url)`

Comment: It is unnecessary to make the methods in your interface public. They are always public by default. `boolean configure() throws Exception;` is enough...

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a `XmlSource` object to `XmlInterface` type reference variable and then use that reference variable to call methods.

```
XmlInterface obj = new XmlSource(surl);
try
{
    boolean configure = obj.configure();
    Document document = obj.load();
}
catch(Exception e){
 // perform exception handling
}
```

Comment: i tried this way but it asks to to handle the exceptions and i don't know where

Comment: You need to surround the code which calls those method in try-catch block because those method declare that they throw exception.